# Indicate a function has no side effects

Tags: c++, function, side-effects, qualifiers

Member functions in C++ may be qualified as `const` to guarantee that they don't alter `this`, but I don't know of anyway to show that a function in general does not cause any changes to any data anywhere.

This would be helpful information to be able to put in a function signature, but I don't know of any way to accomplish this. How can I qualify a function as having no side effects in C++, preferably something not compiler specific but that may be too much to ask

Bonus points if there is a way that works for C as well.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks, I didn't see that one when searching